# PHP Get description tag DomDocument

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm trying to get the description meta tag for my SEO system.

I'm using **Laravel 5.4**

ScanController:

```
$description = $dom->getElementsByTagName('meta')->getAttribute('description');
```

Index:

```
@foreach ($description as $node)
 {{$node->nodeValue, PHP_EOL}}
@endforeach
```

I'm new to this kind of programming so need help.

**Solution:**

I found the fix!

```
@foreach ($description as $node)
  @if($node->getAttribute('name')=='description') 
   {{$node->getAttribute('content'), PHP_EOL}}
  @endif
@endforeach
```

I was especially looking for this line:

```
@if($node->getAttribute('name')=='description')
```

Thanks to M A SIDDIQUI in the comments who gave me a kick in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$description = $dom->getElementsByTagName('meta');
@foreach ($description as $node)
    @if ($node->hasAttribute('content'));
        {{$node->getAttribute('content'), PHP_EOL}}
    @endif
    @else
        {{ "No meta tag found with content attribute"}}
@endforeach
```

eg.

```
<meta name="description" content="this is the meta description content" />
```

You need to foreach the tag and get the attribute and not the nodeValue, i am not much good in laravel so close @else i dont know how to do that.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply.I've tried this but it still doesn't get anything. When i change 'description' to 'content' it gives something but not the thing i want. Do you have another solution?

Comment: Hi please look on modified answer

Comment: Thanks again. But it's still not working. 

It just says "No meta tag found...." but there is a meta description tag. 
Also, if i change description to content it loads all meta tags.